# Modifying a javascript search Engine

Tags: html, database, search

I have been looking all over the place to try to find an answer to a java related question. I am not very good with computers and I usually only delve into the realm of html for my requirements. However; I need to use java for a few aspects of my webpage and I am stumped.

I have a research database that contains approximately 200 articles. Each article is a parent window with two child frames. I know there will be people who will tell me why frames are bad and why I should use css; but I already have over 200 articles completed and I do not want to go and redo everything. I downloaded the code for a really cool internal java web search that was made by Satadip Dutta. [-Link Here-](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3456871) The code works great to retrieve results based on a keyword search. What I am trying to do is make a slight modification to the code so that when a user clicks on a result link... That link is opened in the parent window rather than the child frame the results are displayed in.
Basically my search page has a mainFrame window (Child) and a quick link Frame (Child) and they both open in the parent window. The search page opens in the mainFrame and displays results in the mainFrame, I would like the links, when clicked by a user, to open in the parent window rather than the mainFrame.

I would like to keep this layout format, if possible, because it flows with the rest of the site design. Any help anybody could give would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you
Eric

P.S I am attempting right now to copy and paste my code for the search page located in the mainFrame... I am having issues doing it so the code can be found: 
http://www.mirofoss.com/Database/Database_Datasheet/Mineral_Index.htm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Good day.

Comment: By the way I just looked at that link and that is Javascript not Java.

Comment: I wrote the wrong word in... A apologize, let me correct that

Answer (score 1):

HTML anchor tags (the a tags) can have a target attribute that you set to the name of the frame. Something like:

```
<a href="<<resultlink>>" target="topframe">...</a>
```

Simply modify the search engine code to output the target attribute with whatever frame name you are using for the top frame.

Comment: I understnad in theory how the 
<a href="<<resultlink>>" target="topframe">...</a>
code would work. I have no clue where I would put that in the code though... Would it go somewhere in javascript or outside in the header or the body?

Answer (score 0):

I can close this question thread because I have found my own answer in a manner of speaking. I have learned that it is very difficult to get a javascript code to run in the window it was initially accessed from. Therefore I found a workaround to get all of the page results to open in the parent window, rather than trying to get the resulting link(s) to open in the parent window. This is not exactly what I wanted, but it is a pretty good compromise until I find a better way to run a client side search engine... I modified the search results page to place a link back to the search start so in the end it works good...